# String manipulation in java using replaceAll()

Tags: java, regex

I have string of the following form:

```
भन्‍‌ने [-0.4531954191090929, 0.7931147934270654, -0.3875088408737827, -0.09427394940704822, 0.10065554475134718, -0.22044284832864797, 0.3532556916833505, -1.8256229909222224, 0.8036832111904731, 0.3395868096795993]
```

Whereever  `[ or ] or ,` char are present , I just want to remove them and i want each of the word and float separated by a space. It is follows:

```
भन्‍‌ने -0.4531954191090929 0.7931147934270654 -0.3875088408737827 -0.09427394940704822 0.10065554475134718 -0.22044284832864797 0.3532556916833505 -1.8256229909222224 0.8036832111904731 0.3395868096795993
```

I am representing each of these string as `line`. i did following:

```
line.replaceAll("([|]|,)$", " ");
```

But it didn't work for me. There was nothing change in the input line. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Why not just do 3 `replaceAll` calls, one for each character you want to remove?

Comment: regex is more performatic than a loop, but I agree, a loop is less complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable. Try

```
line = line.replaceAll("([|]|,)$", " ");
```

Or to be a bit more verbose, but avoiding regular expressions:

```
char subst = ' ';
line = line.replace('[', subst).replace(']', subst).replace(',', subst);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), meaning that the contents of a string never change.  So, calling

```
line.replaceAll("([|]|,)$", " ");
```

won't change the contents of `line`, but will return a new string.  You need to assign the result of the method call to a variable.  For instance, if you don't care about the original `line`, you can write

```
line = line.replaceAll("([|]|,)$", " ");
```

to get the effect you originally expected.

Answer (score 1):

`[` and `]` are special characters in a regular expression.  replaceAll is expected a regular expression as its first input, so you have to escape them.

```
String result = line.replaceAll("[\\[\\],]", " ");
```

Cannot tell what you were trying to do with your original regex, why you had the $ there etc, would need to understand what you were expecting the things you put there to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
line = "asdf [foo, bar, baz]".replaceAll("(\\[|\\]|,)", "");
```

The regex syntax uses `[]` to define groups like `[a-z]` so you have to mask them.